# Emacs: split window size in python-mode

Tags: python, emacs, emacs24, python-mode

I set `split-width-threshold` to `nil`, so on execution the python shell will appear in a split window below. However, the shell always occupies half of the frame. Is it possible to adjust the size (automatically on execution)?

The `py-split-windows-on-execute-function` seems to only accept two options (`split-window-vertically` and `split-window-horizontally`).

Emacs version: 24.3

Comment: Your thread is the only webpage in the entire world of Google search that has the term `py-split-windows-on-execution-function`.  Are you sure it is spelled correctly?  I didn't find it in the 01/01/2014 Emacs Trunk source either.

Comment: @lawlist That's a typo. Read ...on-execute-function - a customizable variable of python-mode.el.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler Ah, yes you are right. It should have been "execute" not "execution". Thanks.

Comment: How do you split vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, IMO that's a reasonable request.
It's here now:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1266169

After further reflection, the following result:
Shrinking the output-buffer only has effect for a very limited number of events. Afterward the buffer is filled and window-size is half-way like the current default.

From this don't see it's justified to hard-code it.

Also there is a solution, which seems to come nearby the desired behavior:

```
  M-x python RET
```

switch to py-shell resp. output-buffer and

M-x shrink-window-if-larger-than-buffer RET,
  it's on <kbd>C-x -</kbd>

Than `M-x customize-variable RET py-keep-windows-configuration RET`

to `t' or 'force

The following run should keep the window small, resp. enlarged.

To make customization easier, extended the menu:
  Python/Customize/Switches/Display/py-keep-windows-configuration